# Automatically adjust the height of WebControl

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

I have a web control with some properties set.Below is the code.

In .CS file :

```
    webBrowser1.NavigateToString("<html><head></head><body bgcolor=#d5e1f3><p style=font-family:arial><font size=3><center>" + content + "</center></font></p></body></html>");
```

In XAML :

```xml
<Grid MinHeight="80" 
              Grid.Row="3"
              Background="Red"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                              MinHeight="80"
                              Foreground="Black" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"></phone:WebBrowser>
        </Grid>
```

if the text is one line then its not centered vertically.How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Auto sizing doesn't work for the `WebBrowser` control.

But you could create a workaround by adding script inside which would send the document height outside to your C# app. You could then use that value to manually change the height of the control. Although I am not sure if those two sizes are similar at all.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks can you show me any piece of code that i can add it ? or can you please help me on that ?

Comment: I don't have such code, it was an idea. Do you know how to write javascript code? Do you know how to invoke C# code from js?

Comment: No idea how to do that

Comment: just have a look here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: Why don't you check it yourself?